# Корень слова "подъём"

Tags: словообразование

Как определить корень слова "подъём"?

Comment: Советую делать домашие задание самостоятельно, а то так и останетесь малограмотным (-ной).

Answer (score 1):

Корень — ЁМ, как и в словах СЪЁМ, ПРИЁМ, ОБЪЁМ ...